# Trouble installing and running elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, installation, apt

Yes, I have thoroughly searched for another answer to this question but have yet to find one.

I tried installing first by following the instructions on this page: http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-repositories.html

I am not sure what to do after this step.  It seems that is has installed correctly, but I don't know how to run it.  (I am using PuTTY.)  Can I import it into my module now and being using it, or is there something else I should do?

Here are some attempts I've made:

```
deloacha@azdev-deloacha:~$ bin/elasticsearch.bat
-bash: bin/elasticsearch.bat: No such file or directory
deloacha@azdev-deloacha:~$ cd elasticsearch-1.5.1/bin
-bash: cd: elasticsearch-1.5.1/bin: No such file or directory
deloacha@azdev-deloacha:~$ cd elasticsearch-1.5.1
-bash: cd: elasticsearch-1.5.1: No such file or directory
deloacha@azdev-deloacha:~$ cd ..
deloacha@azdev-deloacha:/home$ cd elasticsearch-1.5.1
-bash: cd: elasticsearch-1.5.1: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the way as provided in the document can sometimes leads to confusion. You need to find the directory containing the elasticsearch files. most probably it'll be at "/etc/elast...."

Another easy way of installation follow the steps:

1. make a directory where you want to install
2. go to that directory and download elasticsearch there using

   wget https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-1.5.1.tar.gz or curl
3. extract files: tar -zxvf elasticsearch-1.5.1.tar.gz
4. cd elasticsearch-1.5.1
5. You need to have java 7 on your system. you can start elasticsearch using "bin/elasticsearch -d" . "-d" is to run in detached mode.
6. Logs are by default in the location elasticsearch-1.5.1/logs. Check logs for any error during start up.
7. check status at: http://localhost:9200  or  http://{system ip}:9200